Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos - Convergence of a Map to the Logistic Map
The cosine–map is defined as:xn+1 = r/4((a+1)cos[k(xn - 1/2)]-a), with k = 2arccos(a/a+1), a > 0.

Show that in the limit a → ∞, the cosine–map is the logistic map.

I am really struggling in where to start for this - I have been hinted at the potential use of L'Hopital's Rule and Taylor series expansions.
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, teach yourself the $\tt MathJax$ Tutorial.

It’s not clear what is $x_{n + 1}$.

I would first start off with taking a Taylor Series of first:
arccos(1-x). This will remove the constant pi/2 from the Taylor series, making it easier to solve.
Evaluating this limit as a -> infinity, you should see that k = sqrt(2/a+1)
Secondly:
cos(y). You will see as a approaches infinity, k approaches 0 (see above).
This leaves:
cos[k(xn - 1/2)] = 1 - (4/(a+1))*(xn - 1/2)^2.
Subbing this into the initial equation you get:
(r/4)*((a+1)(1-(4/(a+1))(xn - 1/2)^2 - a)
Expand this out, collect like terms etc you get:
xn+1 = (r/4)*(-4xn^2 + 4xn) = rxn(1-xn) which is the logistic map. (More working required)

Please use mathjax for your math. I'll be easier to read.
